# Can't connect to nodejs express app with proxy

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I have an node js express app generated in WebStorm, I did not change nothing, it works for me on local network at home where I don't have proxy, but at University I have to set up proxy, and there app it's not working. I set up proxy in WebStorm but still not working...

[Server running in WebStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d67j9.png)

[Proxy Settings and local ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itzve.png)

```
Error Message:

ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://192.168.0.101:3000/

The following error was encountered:

Connection to 192.168.0.101 Failed
The system returned:

    (113) No route to host
The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Your cache administrator is it-suport@ase.ro. 
Generated Fri, 02 Jun 2017 12:54:28 GMT by cache.ase.ro (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
```

Comment: i hope there is a firewall issue..check whether port 3000 is already used or blocked by admin

Comment: https://ibb.co/iUQ4av

Comment: I also tried with another ports, and the error still persist..

Comment: Are you tryng to connect with your app running at home from University? Did u forward your 3000 port from your router settings?

Comment: No, server is running on my notebook in the same wireless lan at University, both server and client have proxy, I tried to turn off proxy and it's works... Why proxy blocking the request to server?